# How to present boring facts that aren't really suitable for an infographic in an interesting way?

Tags: info-visualisation, information-architecture, user-engagement

For an internal company wiki I want to write down/present some basic information regarding web development/design/UI & UX. For example have I collected some studies and opinions on how links should look like. Now I want to present this information in a nice way, but I have literally *no idea* how to do that.

I've already created a PDF file containing the most important facts, but while its nice to look at, its not very encouraging to read because, well, the facts are plain boring.

> Nielsen says in his paper that links should be colored blue, which is backed up by study XYZ. He also says that even if the links on a webpage are not blue, the text on a webpage should never be blue because...

Its that type of information I want to present in an interesting way. Are there any best practices to do that – design-, tone-, medium-wise (PDF, presentation, webpage...)?

Answer (score 7):

Find the story in the data--the story that your audience needs and wants to hear.

(If the data is boring to you then you haven't found your story yet.)

Some questions to help define your purpose:

- Why does this audience need to know basic info regarding web design/etc.?
- What will they do with the information? What will they take home to their desk?
- What is the function of the communication? Information, entertainment, do you want to change behavior, do you want a raise, are you trying to increase awareness and get more people to call in UX people for their projects...what?

Only after you've got a place to stand on these fronts can you figure out how to present the information. The answer will speak directly to medium and tone (both great thing to think about).

Comment: Great answer. Don't paint numbers, paint a story.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered removing the boring data entirely?

Sometimes it takes courage to simplify, but you'll probably be glad you did :)

Comment: -1 The entire point is to communicate the information in those data. "Simplifiying" them away would defeat that point.